# getting the edges of objects in an image from a label_image

Tags: python, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have a `label_image` which is actually an array that assigns each pixel of an image to a real life object. Hence for example, if the `label_image` looks like that

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
0,1,1,1,0,2,0,0
0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0
0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

then it can be understood that my picture shows two objects, one squared-shaped (towards to top-left corner, labelled as the first object) and another diamond-shaped (close to the bottom-right corner, labeled as the second object)
with zeros denoting the background.

How can I get the edges/boundaries/outlines of the objects from that `label_image` please? In this oversimplified example I want to end-up with:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0
0,1,1,1,0,2,0,0
0,0,0,0,2,0,2,0
0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I am using Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with scipy's binary_erosion:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage 

eee = np.array([
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

mask =  ndimage.binary_erosion(eee.tolist())
eee[mask]=0
```

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If may be a good idea to consider your image as a matrix of strings (each label is a string, even it looks like an integer), so as you can benefit from the `count` builtin method for strings:

```
mat = """
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
0,1,1,1,0,2,0,0
0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0
0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
"""

# convert multi-line string into a matrix of string labels ('0','1' or '2')
mat = [line.split(',') for line in mat.strip().split('\n')]
# get matrix dimensions
rows, cols = len(mat), len(mat[0])

indices = []
for row in range(1, rows-1):
  for col in range(1, cols-1):
    # concatenate the labels of the 4 neighbors (N,S,W,E) for the current cell
    nb = mat[row-1][col] + mat[row+1][col] + mat[row][col-1] + mat[row][col+1]
    # if all neighbors have same label as current cell --> store pixel index
    if nb.count(mat[row][col]) == 4:
      indices.append((row,col))

for row, col in indices: # loop over all previously found interior pixels
  mat[row][col] = '0' # force pixel label to '0'

print(mat)
```

Output:

```
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '2', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '0', '2', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

**Note:** If you want the same matrix for the input and the output (as done in the code above), you have to chain two different loops: the first one detects all interior pixels (and stores their indices into a list) while the second one loops over the stored indices and sets the corresponding pixels to '0'. If you can afford a second matrix to store the output, the whole process may be done in the first loop.